# SQL Management Studio login using UPC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, active-directory, upn

We upgraded our legacy Active Directory, which used NETBIOS\username for login. The new UPN convention is username@domain.com  but how do I change SQL Management Studio to use this new  convention? (The User Name is greyed out, and since it maps to  the same user in AD, I don't  want to use the "net use " trick.)

Comment: Does the old convention no longer work? I thought both would. Maybe "Credential" mapping is the solution for you here.

Comment: Are you unable to connect? SSMS should just pull the token of the currently logged in user when using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Yes, unable  to connect.  However, I think the real issue is that the SQL server is in Azure, and Azure Domain Services has no knowledge of NETBIOS\username .